# Code resets the height of banner and overlaps the content beneath slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

following is the link to my slider.
https://nawishta.com/

Exactly beneath the slider, there is an image. On every slide movement, the image beneath the slider suddenly goes up and then comes down. How to make it freeze like normal it should be?

As the wordpress plugin for this slider is not correctly working, so I had manually put the height adjustment in CSS as follows:

```
.soliloquy-slider, .soliloquy-slides, .soliloquy-wrap, .soliloquy-clear {
    height: 600px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}


.soliloquy-item, .soliloquy-item-1, .soliloquy-id-352, .soliloquy-image-slide {
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

If I do not enforce 600px into CSS, the slider would crop the images and that would look bad, so its necessary. The code for slider is available on the page. I'm also attaching its html code here, but its better visible on page [(PAGE LINK)](https://nawishta.com/):

```
<div class="soliloquy-outer-container" data-soliloquy-loaded="1"><div aria-live="polite" id="soliloquy-container-351" class="soliloquy-container soliloquy-transition-fade soliloquy-fade soliloquy-controls-active soliloquy-arrows-active  soliloquy-theme-base" style="max-width: 960px; max-height: 300px; margin: 0px auto 20px; height: auto; opacity: 1; background-image: none;"><div class="soliloquy-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;"><div class="soliloquy-viewport" style="width: 100%; position: relative; height: 600px;"><ul id="soliloquy-351" class="soliloquy-slider soliloquy-slides soliloquy-wrap soliloquy-clear" style="width: auto; position: relative;"><li aria-hidden="false" class="soliloquy-item soliloquy-item-1 soliloquy-id-352 soliloquy-image-slide soliloquy-active-slide" draggable="false" style="list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 50; display: block; margin-right: -100%;"><code id="soliloquy-slug-shortcode" class="soliloquy-code"><img id="soliloquy-image-352" class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-image-1" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/552e46dc-e97a-40c6-885c-2541caf8d0fd.jpg" alt="552e46dc-e97a-40c6-885c-2541caf8d0fd"></code></li><li aria-hidden="true" class="soliloquy-item soliloquy-item-2 soliloquy-id-353 soliloquy-image-slide" draggable="false" style="list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 0; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><code id="soliloquy-slug-shortcode" class="soliloquy-code"><img id="soliloquy-image-353" class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-image-2 soliloquy-preload" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/576b9a8e-2916-4046-adf9-57707bbad648.jpg" alt="576b9a8e-2916-4046-adf9-57707bbad648"></code></li><li aria-hidden="true" class="soliloquy-item soliloquy-item-3 soliloquy-id-354 soliloquy-image-slide" draggable="false" style="list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 0; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><code id="soliloquy-slug-shortcode" class="soliloquy-code"><img id="soliloquy-image-354" class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-image-3 soliloquy-preload" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/2d75e297-802b-4793-be56-4ce8c605eedc.jpg" alt="2d75e297-802b-4793-be56-4ce8c605eedc"></code></li><li aria-hidden="true" class="soliloquy-item soliloquy-item-4 soliloquy-id-355 soliloquy-image-slide" draggable="false" style="list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 0; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><code id="soliloquy-slug-shortcode" class="soliloquy-code"><img id="soliloquy-image-355" class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-image-4 soliloquy-preload" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/f9b56abd-95be-4af7-a15c-b2989a687e85.jpg" alt="f9b56abd-95be-4af7-a15c-b2989a687e85"></code></li><li aria-hidden="true" class="soliloquy-item soliloquy-item-5 soliloquy-id-356 soliloquy-image-slide" draggable="false" style="list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 0; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><code id="soliloquy-slug-shortcode" class="soliloquy-code"><img id="soliloquy-image-356" class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-image-5 soliloquy-preload" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/0c9533f7-fe4b-4b0b-9509-1ed2a219d40f.jpg" alt="0c9533f7-fe4b-4b0b-9509-1ed2a219d40f"></code></li></ul></div><div class="soliloquy-controls soliloquy-has-pager soliloquy-has-controls-direction" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="soliloquy-pager soliloquy-default-pager"><div class="soliloquy-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="soliloquy-pager-link active" tabindex="0"><span>1</span></a></div><div class="soliloquy-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="soliloquy-pager-link" tabindex="0"><span>2</span></a></div><div class="soliloquy-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="2" class="soliloquy-pager-link" tabindex="0"><span>3</span></a></div><div class="soliloquy-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="3" class="soliloquy-pager-link" tabindex="0"><span>4</span></a></div><div class="soliloquy-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="4" class="soliloquy-pager-link" tabindex="0"><span>5</span></a></div></div><div class="soliloquy-controls-direction" aria-label="carousel buttons" aria-controls="soliloquy-container-351"><a class="soliloquy-prev" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="previous"><span></span></a><a class="soliloquy-next" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="next"><span></span></a></div></div></div></div><noscript><style type="text/css" scoped>#soliloquy-container-351{opacity:1}#soliloquy-container-351 li > .soliloquy-caption{display:none}#soliloquy-container-351 li:first-child > .soliloquy-caption{display:block}</style><div class="soliloquy-no-js" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0;line-height:0;opacity:0;"><img class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-no-js-image" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/552e46dc-e97a-40c6-885c-2541caf8d0fd.jpg" alt="552e46dc-e97a-40c6-885c-2541caf8d0fd" /><img class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-no-js-image" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/576b9a8e-2916-4046-adf9-57707bbad648.jpg" alt="576b9a8e-2916-4046-adf9-57707bbad648" /><img class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-no-js-image" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/2d75e297-802b-4793-be56-4ce8c605eedc.jpg" alt="2d75e297-802b-4793-be56-4ce8c605eedc" /><img class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-no-js-image" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/f9b56abd-95be-4af7-a15c-b2989a687e85.jpg" alt="f9b56abd-95be-4af7-a15c-b2989a687e85" /><img class="soliloquy-image soliloquy-no-js-image" src="https://nawishta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/0c9533f7-fe4b-4b0b-9509-1ed2a219d40f.jpg" alt="0c9533f7-fe4b-4b0b-9509-1ed2a219d40f" /></div></noscript></div>
```

Need to make the image do not automatically come up for a glimpse whenever the next slide image is loaded into the slider.

Answer (score 1):

Your slider adds `overflow: hidden` to the class which makes `position: relative` useless. You need to give your parent class a minimum-heigh so whenever the slider height collapses it doesn't change its height.

This should work.

```
.soliloquy-outer-container {
   min-height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to the list of things you want 600px in your CSS.

```
.soliloquy-theme-base{
  max-height: 600px !important;
}
```